# deploying .war on docker container running tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

I've been trying to deploy a webapp on a docker container image, I'm using tutum/tomcat. After I run the container and try to deploy the war file using /manager/html it shows me the following error message:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /1.0 could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/1.0]]
```

Also by using docker logs [container-id]:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : error in opening zip file
```

Comment: get into that container with `docker exec -it container_id bash` and check that your .war is here, like you would debug on any server

Comment: I checked and is inside $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ where it should be but is giving me the same error {java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : error in opening zip file}

Comment: Maybe in the container you lack some component that is installed in a full OS, but not in your container ?